# Unable to convert Magento object array response to json format

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, magento

I am trying to convert a magento object array to json, but it is giving the result `{}`.

```
$facetColor = Mage::getModel('facets/color')->getCollection();
```

printing the array gives me

```
print "<pre>";
print_r($facetColor);

gamer_Facets_Model_Resource_Color_Collection Object
(
    [_joinedFields:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [_model:protected] => facets/color
    [_resourceModel:protected] => facets/color
    [_resource:protected] => Gamer_Facets_Model_Resource_Color Object
        (
            [_resources:protected] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource Object
                (
                    [_connectionTypes:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [_connections:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [core_read] => Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql Object
                                (
                                    [_defaultStmtClass:protected] => Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql
                                    [_transactionLevel:protected] => 0
                                    [_connectionFlagsSet:protected] => 1
                                    [_ddlCache:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [log_visitor_info] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [visitor_id] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [SCHEMA_NAME] => 
                                                                    [TABLE_NAME] => log_visitor_info
                                                                    [COLUMN_NAME] => visitor_id
                                                                    [COLUMN_POSITION] => 1
                                                                    [DATA_TYPE] => bigint
                                                                    [DEFAULT] => 0
                                                                    [NULLABLE] => 
                                                                    [LENGTH] => 
                                                                    [SCALE] => 
                                                                    [PRECISION] => 
                                                                    [UNSIGNED] => 1
                                                                    [PRIMARY] => 1
                                                                    [PRIMARY_POSITION] => 1
                                                                    [IDENTITY] => 
                                                                )

                                                            [http_referer] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [SCHEMA_NAME] => 
                                                                    [TABLE_NAME] => log_visitor_info
                                                                    [COLUMN_NAME] => http_referer
                                                                    [COLUMN_POSITION] => 2
                                                                    [DATA_TYPE] => varchar
                                                                    [DEFAULT] => 
                                                                    [NULLABLE] => 1
                                                                    [LENGTH] => 255
                                                                    [SCALE] => 
                                                                    [PRECISION] => 
                                                                    [UNSIGNED] => 
                                                                    [PRIMARY] => 
                                                                    [PRIMARY_POSITION] => 
                                                                    [IDENTITY] => 
                                                                )
```

then i use this code to convert it into the json format:

```
$jsonData = Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode((array)$facetColor);
echo $jsonData;
```

and get the result `{}`.

I also tried to use the `json_encode` function, but still no luck, same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following :

```
$jsonData = Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($facetColor->getData());
```

or

`$jsonData = json_encode($facetColor->getData());`

Hope this helps!!

Comment: thanks @Reena Parekh  for reply i just look it into the code and tell you shortly

Comment: still no luck now it is displaying blank screen

Comment: Are you sure you are getting data in your collection ? I think you are getting an empty collection. You can check it with $facetColor->getSize() .. The output of getSize should be greater than 0.

Comment: sorry previous i miss some thing i got 8 count

Comment: hi Reena i had posted my array out put above in question it self

Comment: if you are getting count 8 then the above code should be working. Cross-Check with some other collection like product collection for example. 

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$test = $collection->getData();
$test2 =  json_encode($test);
echo "<pre>";
echo $test2;
echo "</pre>";